# Namespace and identifier in c++ with dllexport

Tags: c++, namespaces, identifier, dllexport

Does anybody know how this

```
namespace my_ns {
    void Load() {}
}
using namespace my_ns;
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void my_dll_function() {
    ::my_ns::Load();
}
```

differs from

```
namespace my_ns {
    void Load() {}
    extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void my_dll_function() {
        Load();
    }
}
```

or why one would consider the first one as a better solution than the second?
Please notice the `dllexport` and `extern` 'keywords'!

Comment: No difference (from point of view of a caller in another DLL). BTW "using namespace" in first example is useless because you specify namespace when you call Load().

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I was thinking, too. I just read this in a project I am working on and wasn't sure about it, especially because of the call to `::my_ns::Load()`. I thought maybe it changes behaviour in a special case or something. If you are sure about that post it as answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: OK, done. I tried to write down few more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference (from point of view of a caller inside another DLL), exported function name (because of `extern  "C"`) has no reference to namespace (you can check it with Dependency Walker).

It means that it doesn't matter where `my_dll_function()` is placed, it'll be always imported in the namespace where it'll be declared (with `__declspec(dllimport)`). This has a somehow big implication: you can't declare more than one exported function (with `extern "C"`) with a given name (even if you - try to - declare them in different namespaces). From C++ specifications (§ 7.5):

> ...At most one function with a particular name can have C language linkage. Two declarations for a function with C language linkage with the same function name (ignoring the namespace names that qualify it) that appear in different namespace scopes refer to the same function...

---

<sub>Just another side note: in your first example `using namespace my_ns` is useless because you call function using full namespace `::my_ns::Load()`.</sub>

Comment: I believe that be --> "extern "C" and not --> export "C" ?

Comment: Yes, definitely! Fixed, tnx